# How to Refresh the rad grid with out reload the page

Tags: telerik

I have Master grid when i selected row based on selcted row i have display more than two rad grids based on selected row for these rad grid i have add ,edit delete when i click add link it is oen rad window addd  adding record and page reload but i dont want to reload page i want refresh which grid is i added recoed for that i have use following code

```
   <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdFiles" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdResource" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdMessages" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdTasks" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdFiles">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdFiles" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
             <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdResource">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdResource" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdMessages">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdMessages" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
             <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdTasks">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdTasks" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

in code behind

protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == "Rebind")
        {

```
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        RadGrid1.Rebind();

        grdFiles.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdFiles.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdFiles.Rebind();

        grdResource.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdResource.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdResource.Rebind();

        grdMessages.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdMessages.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdMessages.Rebind();

        grdTasks.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdTasks.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdTasks.Rebind();


    }
    else if (e.Argument == "RebindAndNavigate")
    {
        RadXmlHttpPanel1.RegisterWithScriptManager = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount - 1;
        RadGrid1.Rebind();

        grdFiles.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdFiles.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdFiles.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount - 1;
        grdFiles.Rebind();

        grdResource.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdResource.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdResource.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount - 1;
        grdResource.Rebind();

        grdMessages.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdMessages.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdMessages.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount - 1;
        grdMessages.Rebind();

        grdTasks.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
        grdTasks.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
        grdTasks.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount - 1;
        grdTasks.Rebind();
    }
}
```

please help me how to resolve this issue

Regar

Answer (score 0):

call ajaxRequest() method in order to fire the OnItemsRequested server event:

```
function clientClick() {
        var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>");
        ajaxManager.ajaxRequest("client");
    }
```